# sql - normalize user table with it groups but both can login

Tags: mysql, normalization

Hi currently i have 3 tables:

```
users
|id|name|email|password|last_login|created_at|

user_groups
|user_id|group_id

groups
|group_id|name|email|password|last_login|created_at|
```

Group can login so it when i can view statistics for specific all it users, that's why i put email and password too.

the problem is users and groups got almost everything same. 1 group can contain many users.
Is there anyway to make this more normalize and user still have their specific groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the user authentication to detect whether the user belongs to any group or not. That way you don't need all these extra fields for the group.

If you only want one specific user to be able to look at the group statistics you could add an admin_id to the user_groups table (which would relate to a user id)

Comment: this!. i love you ppl at SO. i always think something complicate, but ignore something simple like this. Thanks man!